# Antibot Failing when Webform Embeded in Gutenberg

Tags: webforms, caching, 8

When enabling [Antibot](https://www.drupal.org/project/antibot) on a [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/) rendered through [Guntenberg](https://www.drupal.org/project/gutenberg/), I can not submit the form.

1. Create a "Custom Webform" block type with a single entity reference field for Webforms.
2. Create a block (of type "Custom Webform") that references a "Booking" webform
3. Go to the setting of my "Basic Page" content type and  allows users to include the webform block

However, when I enable Antibot on the webform and try saving the form, I get the error:

> You have reached this page because you submitted a form that required
> JavaScript to be enabled on your browser. This protection is in place
> to attempt to prevent automated submissions made on forms. Please
> return to the page that you came from and enable JavaScript on your
> browser before attempting to submit the form again.

I've tried enabling Ajax with no success. I suspect this is a caching issue: when I edit the label of a input field, I have to flush all caches to see the changes reflected.

Currently, exploring lazy loading the block.

Comment: *I suspect this is a caching issue: when I edit the label of a input field, I have to flush all caches to see the changes reflected.* So you are missing two things, the antibot javascript library and the cache metadata of the webform. I suspect the render pipeline in your setup is loosing all metadata at some point. What if you use a webform block directly instead of a block type? What if you place the block in the block layout instead of Gutenberg?

Comment: I've seen Gutenberg fixed a lot of issues but they never tagged a new release. Try the latest dev version.

Comment: @4k4 Sorry for the late response! I upgraded the module from 8.x-1.14 to 8.x-2.2 and it's working now. Do you want to post an answer?